# unable to move javascript from html file into js file and import it into application.js - rails

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript (a progress bar) which works fine in script tags in html. however im trying to move it into a .js file and import into application.js but i'm not sure how. ive done it before with another javascript feature where i put the whole thing in a function,(i've added function bar() here)  then exported that, then imported in application.js, however it is not working this time. im quite new to javascript, thanks.

```js
  function bar(){
     $('.progress-wrap').each(function(){
    percent = $(this);
    bar = $(this).children('.progress-bar');
    moveProgressBar(percent, bar);
});

  // function bar(){
  // on browser resize...
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.progress-wrap').each(function(){
        percent = $(this);
        bar = $(this).children('.progress-bar');
        moveProgressBar(percent, bar);
    });
  });

  // SIGNATURE PROGRESS
  function moveProgressBar(percent, bar) {
      var getPercent = (percent.data('progress-percent') / 100);
      var getProgressWrapWidth = percent.width();
      var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
      var animationLength = 1000;

      // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
      // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
      bar.stop().animate({
          left: progressTotal
      }, animationLength);
  }
}

export {bar};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to give a an exact answer without your complete html file and code. But in some cases the problem is the order. That you use jQuery or other libs for example that are not available at this time.

Normally you should change your script in that way that it's running first if everything else is ready. In you script you use jQuery so you could use

```
$(document).ready(function());
```

Then you script runs first if your document is ready.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

You could check all that with your Developer Tools in your browser and check if you can see some errors that something is missing.